# Xamarin.Forms MediaManager play video from local storage

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin.forms

I am creating custom cross-platform video player with MediaManager.
It plays video from https but I want it play video from local storage.

```
        var folder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);
        folder = Path.Combine(folder, "UserVideos/testvideo.mp4");
        videoPlayer.Source = folder;
        CrossMediaManager.Current.Play("file://" + "/UserVideos/testvideo.mp4");
```

I tried this way, but it doesn't play video.
Folder UserVideos is in main namespace.

Comment: Unfortunately all media plugins for Xamarin that I know are buggy, you have to implement it yourself...

Comment: Maybe you right...

Comment: the docs specifically address this - https://github.com/Baseflow/XamarinMediaManager#other-play-possibilities

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Would you confirm whether the file `testvideo.mp4` is stored in internal storage or external storage? From your code, I guess that you want to get video from internal storage, but files in internal storage that cannot be shared, and you don't see it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/files/#internal-vs-external-storage

So when using a file:// based URL, I suggest you can copy your video in **Assets folder** and **BuildAction** is **AndroidAsset**.

Then play video like this:

```
CrossMediaManager.Current.Play("file:///android_asset/minions.mp4");
```

I install **Plugin.MediaManager.Forms** by Nuget package, then init in Mainactivity.cs:

```
CrossMediaManager.Current.Init(this);
```

MainPage.xaml:

```
 <StackLayout>
        <video:VideoView HeightRequest="300" WidthRequest="200" />

        <Button Text="play local video" Clicked="BtnPlayLocal_Clicked"/>
    </StackLayout>



 private void BtnPlayLocal_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
        CrossMediaManager.Current.Play("file:///android_asset/minions.mp4");
    }
```

[image]

### Update

If you want to play video in Xamarin.ios, please add video in **Resource folder** and **BuildAction** is **BundleResource**

Then Play video like this:

```
CrossMediaManager.Current.PlayFromResource("minions.mp4");
```

Full code:

```
private  void BtnPlayLocal_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS)
        {
            CrossMediaManager.Current.PlayFromResource("minions.mp4");
        }
        else if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android)
        {
            CrossMediaManager.Current.Play("file:///android_asset/minions.mp4");
        }

    }
```

Here is the sample in Github:

https://github.com/CherryBu/VideoSample

Comment: how can I play local in iOS? Thank you very much for your answer

Comment: @Bogdan, Please take a look my update, if my reply help you, please remember to mark my reply as answer, thanks.

Comment: GitHub link leads to a deleted repo. Is the code still available anywhere else?